# What does '(list 1 2) means in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm studying SICP and at the beginning of section 2.2.2 it gives the following code: `(cons '(list 1 2) (list 3 4)))` and says it constructs a list like `((1 2) 3 4)`. But when I typed it into DrRacket(I'm using Racket here actually) it produces `'((list 1 2) 3 4)` and if I write `(cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4))` then it'll be alright. I know in Scheme `'(1 2)` is equal to `(list 1 2)` but what does `'(list 1 2)` mean?

Comment: It does not. I have a copy of SICP in front of me and the code is not `(cons '(list 1 2) (list 3 4)))`.  It is  `(cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4))`.

Comment: OK then there must be sth wrong with my copy. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation `'foo` makes a symbol named foo.

The notation `'(foo bar)` makes a list with two symbols named `foo` and `bar`.

In the same way `'(list foo bar)` makes a list of three symbols. The symbol `'list` happens to be called `list`.

Now `(list 'foo 'bar)` makes a list of two symbols called `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Why `'(foo bar)` is correct but `(list foo bar)` is wrong? Both are making a list with 2 unknown identifier.

Comment: In `(list foo bar)` the system 1) looks up what `list` is and finds the list constructor 2) looks up `foo` and finds out it is undefined.

Comment: But in `'(foo bar)` foo seems also undefined.

Comment: The `'` means construct a value that prints as `(foo bar)`. The system changes `'(foo bar)` to `(list 'foo 'bar)`.

Comment: Can I say `'(foo bar)` just declares a list variable which consists of two other variables foo and bar, but not yet binding to a value?

Comment: No. `'(foo bar)` creates a list with two elements. The first element is the symbol `'foo` and the second element is the symbol `'bar`. Symbols aren't variables. Symbols are more-or-less the same as strings.

Comment: Umm...I can understand now but symbols seem of little use.

Comment: The difference between symbols and strings is that it is very fast to compare strings to see if they are equal. See the answer to this question for a full explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846628/what-exactly-is-a-symbol-in-lisp-scheme

Answer (score 3):

It should mean "a list consisting of the atom list, the atom 1, and the atom 2". Until Scheme evaluates the list (which the single quote prevents), it doesn't treat "list" differently from any other string.

Comment: Thanks but I can only adopt one answer.

Answer (score 2):

*Scheme has a convenient syntax for representing data literals: prefix any expression with ' (single quote) and the expression, rather than being evaluated, will be returned as data*

For more informations:

http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/04wi/lectures/14-scheme-quote.html

Comment: Thanks as well but I can only adopt one answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Fix output style**

First off, When you use the `#!racket` language in DrRacket, the default way of printing is not printing it's representation but an expression that evaluates to the same. You can turn it off from the menu **language** >> **choose language**. You select <kbd>Show details</kbd> and under Output style you select **write**

After pressing <kbd>Run</kbd>, when evaluating `'test` you will get the output `test`.

**Typo in expression**

In [section 2.2.2](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%25_sec_2.2.2) there is an expression `(cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4))`. It is **not the same** as what you wrote in the question, `(cons '(list 1 2) (list 3 4))`. While an expression `(list 1 2)` applies the procedure `list` with values `1` and `2` and thus becomes `(1 2)`, the expression `'(list 1 2)` just return the quoted data `(list 1 2)` unchanged.

Thus:

```
(cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4))   ; ==> ((1 2) 3 4)
(cons '(list 1 2) (list 3 4))  ; ==> ((list 1 2) 3 4)
'(cons '(list 1 2) (list 3 4)) ; ==> (cons '(list 1 2) (list 3 4))
```

Comment: Really? But on my book it truly has an extra ' ... So you want to say adding an extra ' is useless?

Comment: @Caesar If you follow the link to 2.2.2 you can clearly see that the web edition hasn't quoted the `list` form. The extra `'` changes how the code is interpreted.  `(+ 1 2 3)` evaluates to `6` while `'(+ 1 2 3)` evaluates to `(+ 1 2 3)` (a list consisting of the symbol `+` and the numbers 1,2, and 3. Same happens with `(list 1 2 3)` except `list` does something else while the result of `'(list 1 2 3)` is the identical result as `'(+ 1 2 3)` except the first symbol is different. Without quote the first procedure in the expression is different.